# scrollview not scrolling android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, scrollview

The ScrollView item is not doing what it should: I can´t scroll.

The code below is a part from a fragment, with splitted screen (thats why I use weight=1). The content of the RelativeLayout is added via code dynamically. The content appears correctly, it is more that could fit onto the screen, so it should be possible to scroll.

I tried out several things:

- changing RelativesLayout-height to wrap-content
- adding fillViewport="true" to the ScrollView
- scrollview not as root element

THE LAYOUT FILE OF THE FRAGMENT

> ```
>   <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/schichten"
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     tools:context="tuerk.fabian.polarfuchs.AllgemeineInfosFragment">
>
>     <ScrollView
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:fillViewport="true" >
>
>         <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/schichten_upper_half"
>             android:isScrollContainer="true"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>             android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>
>
>     </ScrollView>
> ```

THE LAYOUT FILE OF THE CONTENT THAT IS DYNAMICALLY ADDED TO THE FRAGMENT (INTO @+id/schichten_upper_half)

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_haerte"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="FA"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:paddingRight="10sp"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_von_height"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="10 cm"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schichten_ansicht_haerte"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_bis_height"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="10 cm"
>         android:layout_below="@id/schichten_ansicht_von_height"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schichten_ansicht_haerte"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_naesse"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="4"
>         android:textSize="20sp"
>         android:paddingLeft="10sp"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schichten_ansicht_bis_height"/>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_1st_grain_form"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:src="@drawable/df"
>         android:paddingLeft="10sp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/schichten_ansicht_naesse"/>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_2nd_grain_form"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:src="@drawable/df"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/schichten_ansicht_1st_grain_form"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_durchmesser_von"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="0.1 "
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:paddingLeft="10sp"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schichten_ansicht_2nd_grain_form"/>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/schichten_ansicht_durchmesser_bis"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="- 0.3 mm"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/schichten_ansicht_durchmesser_von"/>
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

THE LAYOUT FILE OF THE ACITIVITY

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:id="@+id/appbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
>         android:id="@+id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>     android:id="@+id/container"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
>
> <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>     android:id="@+id/fab"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
>     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
>     app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
> ```

Comment: If there is no content of a ScrollView (or it doesn't take more space than the screen height) it will nto scroll

Comment: yup, that was it. thanks a lot!